# Cycle through css stylesheet files by clicking single div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to swap the CSS stylesheet file without reloading the page. I'm wondering how to cycle through an array of multiple stylesheets by clicking a single source (div, #button), returning to the default, and then continuously looping through the list. It would also be great if the browser could remember what stylesheet the website is currently on for page to page continuity, though this is not necessary. The following is what I have so far...

HTML:

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

<div id="button" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var stylesheets = [
    "style1.css",
    "style2.css",
    "style3.css",
    "default.css"
];

function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

Comment: does it work at all?

Comment: No, there is no function written to make the button div activate swapStyleSheet

Comment: You may want to look at [Alternative Stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets)

Comment: and [selectedStyleSheetSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectedStyleSheetSet) and [styleSheetSets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheetSets) -  at least for current browsers anyway

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be to shuffle the list of stylesheets and render the first one every time:

```
function nextSytlesheet() {
    stylesheets.push(stylesheets.shift());
    swapStyleSheet(stylesheets[0]);
}
```

But, what are you trying to achieve by reloading styles? Every CSS file initiates a GET request to the server, so unless your styles are huge it makes more sense to have one stylesheet per app and dynamically switch classes instead. To simulate the full stylesheet swapping, you can just prepend `.style1` (with trailing space) class to every rule you have in style1.css, do the same for others, and then switch these classes on `<body>` instead of reloading stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your purpose is, but you could just change the class names of elements on the page via a button, and have different styles associated with the classes in your main stylesheet.

Hope this helps! ;)

Edit: Just as Igor said. I didn't see his whole comment till now.

Edit 2: Sorry for the late response, but I was able to make a demo for you!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fakeBody" class="normal">
  <p>Hello There! I change colors!</p>
  <button id="button">Click me to change colors</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.normal, button {
  color: default;
  background-color: default;
}
.light, .light button {
  color: #0000ff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.dark, .dark button {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.wood, .wood button {
  color: #444444;
  background-color: #dbcc48;
}
.textEditor, .textEditor button {
  color: #00ff00;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var body = document.getElementById("fakeBody"),
        themePosition = 0,
    maxThemePosition = 4;
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    themePosition++;
  if (themePosition > maxThemePosition) {
    themePosition = 0;
  }
    if (themePosition == 0) {
      body.className = "normal";
  } else if (themePosition == 1) {
    body.className = "light";
  } else if (themePosition == 2) {
    body.className = "dark";
  } else if (themePosition == 3) {
    body.className = "wood";
  } else if (themePosition == 4) {
    body.className = "textEditor";
  }
});
```

[Working Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Smedium/pd9w68bq/)